# classification and data mining. Difference?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I am working in the area of machine learning and pattern recognition for the last 8-10 years. I use it for image classification and recognition. Recently, I started learning about some Data Mining. How much is data mining related to classification? Or can I as a person with experience on image classification work on data mining?

Answer (score 2):

Classification is one of many *machine learning* techniques used in data mining. But usually, you'd simply use the more precise "machine learning" category for classification.
Data mining is he *explorative* side - you want to understand the data. That can mean learning to predict, but mostly to understand what can be predicted (and what not) and *how* (which features etc.).
In many cases, classification is used in a way that I'd not include in data mining. If you just want to recognize images as cars or not (but don't care about the "why") it's probably not data mining.